# Unable to connect to 802.11 b/g/n mixed WiFi network on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager

I am able to connect to other WiFi networks like my Android hotspot but not to this particular home WiFi. I was able to connect to this WiFi also till some days ago, but unable to connect now.

```
# wireless info START #

Report from: 13 Dec 2018 22:52 IST +0530
Booted last: 13 Dec 2018 00:00 IST +0530
Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

# kernel ##

Linux 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

# desktop ##

Ubuntu

# lspci ##

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:8096]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

# lsusb ####

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 064e:930a Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

# PCMCIA card info ##

# rfkill ###

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

# secure boot ###

SecureBoot enabled

# lsmod ###

rtl8723be            98304  0
btcoexist           135168  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common       24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci              32768  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi              77824  4 rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8723_common,rtl8723be
hp_wmi               16384  0
sparse_keymap        16384  1 hp_wmi
mac80211            778240  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
wmi_bmof             16384  0
cfg80211            622592  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
mxm_wmi              16384  1 nouveau
wmi                  24576  4 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau,hp_wmi

# interfaces ####

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# ifconfig ###

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback  brd 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
3: wlo1:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
    inet 192.168.43.243/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 2245sec preferred_lft 2245sec
    inet6 fe80::5647:b70d:dad6:7da0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# iwconfig ##

eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Leno"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point:    
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=10 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:192   Missed beacon:0

# route ###

default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.243 metric 600 

# resolv.conf #

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53

# network managers ####

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2328     1  0 22:02 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

# NetworkManager info ##

GENERAL.DEVICE:                     wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                       wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                    NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                     Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                    RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                     rtl8723be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:             4.15.0-34-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:           N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                     
GENERAL.MTU:                        1500
GENERAL.STATE:                      100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                     0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                        /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:08:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                   wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                 yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:           no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:          no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:               --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                 Leno
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                   916bf04c-2ff1-409f-8366-b7ff5738d611
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                   /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                    yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:        no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                 72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:           no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                 no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:               yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:               yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:               yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                 yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:              yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:               yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:               no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                     192.168.43.243/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                        192.168.43.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                       dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.43.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                       dst = 192.168.43.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                       dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                         192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                    requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                    subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                    domain_name_servers = 192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                    ip_address = 192.168.43.243
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                    requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                    dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                    requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                    broadcast_address = 192.168.43.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                   requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                   dhcp_rebinding_time = 3002
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                   requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                   dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                   requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                   routers = 192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                   dhcp_renewal_time = 1652
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                   requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                   requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                   expiry = 1544724019
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                   host_name = Skywalker
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                   requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                   requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                   requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                   requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                   network_number = 192.168.43.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                   requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                   next_server = 192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                   requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                   vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                   requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                   dhcp_lease_time = 3600
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                     fe80::5647:b70d:dad6:7da0/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                        --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                       dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                       dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                       dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{6,26}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   f78c463b-568c-4471-a4e8-3c5162f056fd | MTNL 1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   916bf04c-2ff1-409f-8366-b7ff5738d611 | Leno

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:09:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 
Leno    Infra  7     2442 MHz  65 Mbit/s  48      â–‚â–„__  WPA2      yes     *      

# NetworkManager.state ###

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=false

# NetworkManager config ###

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

# NetworkManager profiles ###

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wifi2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wifi2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:prashant:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Wifi2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=wifi | permissions=user:prashant:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=AndroidAP
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TIMBL1568]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TIMBL1568 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TIMBL1568
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIRECT-3F-HP DeskJet 4670 series]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIRECT-3F-HP DeskJet 4670 series | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DIRECT-3F-HP DeskJet 4670 series
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Modern F4]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Modern F4 | type=wifi | permissions=user:prashant:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Modern F4
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MTNL]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MTNL | type=wifi | permissions=user:prashant:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MTNL
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Modern 5F 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Modern 5F 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Modern 5F 1
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=wifi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=wifi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Skywalker]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Skywalker | type=wifi | permissions=user:prashant:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Skywalker
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SingAnnDance]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SingAnnDance | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SingAnnDance
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Airtel]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Airtel | type=wifi | permissions=user:prashant:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Airtel
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Modern 4f]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Modern 4f | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Modern 4f
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TIMBL1568 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TIMBL1568 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TIMBL1568
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Deepak]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Deepak | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Deepak
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Modern 4th floor]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Modern 4th floor | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Modern 4th floor
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MTNL 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MTNL 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MTNL
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Redmi 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Redmi 2 | type=wifi | permissions=user:prashant:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Redmi 2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HIGHAPE]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HIGHAPE | type=wifi | permissions=user:prashant:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HIGHAPE
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Sid]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Sid | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Sid
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Living Room TV.b]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Living Room TV.b | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Living Room TV.b
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/long wifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=long wifi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=long wifi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Leno]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Leno | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Leno
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/New 4th floor 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=New 4th floor 2 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=New 4th floor 2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TIMBL1568 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TIMBL1568 2 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TIMBL1568
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ravi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ravi | type=wifi | permissions=user:prashant:;
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Ravi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Lenovo K8 Note 1912]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Lenovo K8 Note 1912 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Lenovo K8 Note 1912
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

# Netplan config ###

# iw reg get ####

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

# iwlist channels ###

eno1      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlo1      13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency=2.442 GHz (Channel 7)

# iwlist scan ##

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)

wlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:7
                    Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Leno"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000c2773519
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

# module info ###

[rtl8723be]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723be/rtl8723be.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
author:         PageHe  
srcversion:     4460AA5584590927164B1F2
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723be
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1)
 (int)
parm:           debug_level:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
 (int)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
srcversion:     90DB9C652E26F4135F339B8
depends:        rtlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl8723_common
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
author:         lizhaoming  
srcversion:     D883A6C5A490FBE0CDF1B6A
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtl_pci
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
author:         lizhaoming  
srcversion:     12BDF0F9FFC2ACFD3465C5A
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtlwifi
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     76870094CC01F4AC06240B7
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     62FD05DCC5AEEA290640C3D
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

# module parameters ###

[rtl8723be]
ant_sel: 2
aspm: 1
debug_level: 0
debug_mask: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
msi: N
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

# /etc/modules ###

# modprobe options ###

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2

# rc.local ###

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

# pm-utils ###

[/etc/pm/config.d/config] (644 root)
SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"

# udev rules ###

# dmesg ###

[   21.247825] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[   21.247829] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   21.285479] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[   21.298898] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   21.299506] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   21.515979] rtl8723be 0000:08:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   34.103157] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   34.226631] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: link down
[   34.226735] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   34.253693] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)
[   36.527774] wlo1: authenticate with 
[   36.537846] wlo1: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[   36.541084] wlo1: authenticated
[   36.544067] wlo1: associate with  (try 1/3)
[   36.557670] wlo1: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   36.557864] wlo1: associated
[   36.682188] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[  146.194155] wlo1: deauthenticating from  by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  147.074368] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[  147.077648] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)
[  149.271096] wlo1: authenticate with 
[  149.281187] wlo1: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  149.285356] wlo1: authenticated
[  149.287442] wlo1: associate with  (try 1/3)
[  149.310282] wlo1: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  149.310494] wlo1: associated
[  149.324416] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[  194.325762] wlo1: deauthenticating from  by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  219.646756] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[  221.108742] wlo1: authenticate with 
[  221.118836] wlo1: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  221.122203] wlo1: authenticated
[  221.127418] wlo1: associate with  (try 1/3)
[  221.154219] wlo1: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  221.154413] wlo1: associated
[  221.167157] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Please clarify. You appear to be connected perfectly well: "wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Leno" Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz"

Comment: This is my Android network. My home wifi doesn't appear in the network list to connect

Comment: What channel is your home network on? Notice that your wireless device does channels 1-13 only.

Comment: Can you connect to the home network if you are close the to wifi router?

Comment: @Jeremy31 No, its not connecting, even when I put my laptop superclose to router